# What is a code page and what is it's purpose?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I was reading up on database optimization and the differences between certain data types and came along some discussion about code pages.  I couldn't find an easy to grasp explanation.  What is a code page exactly?  What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 1):

A code page is essentially an encoding of a script - of characters.

For example - ASCII encodes English characters in binary (for example, the letter `A` is encoded as decimal 65, or 1000001 in binary).

There are many different encodings - some for specific hardware architectures, some encoding specific human languages and others for data interchange.

A code page in the context of a database is the way you tell the database how to treat text - using what encoding. This is used both for storage and for operations like comparisons and searches.